# How do i make a three-time load attempt in await promise.all and return a default value if it fails

Tags: javascript, async-await, try-catch

I have an asynchronous function in a worker to load image data. This almost always works without any problems. Sometimes a loading process does not seem to work right away and then I no longer get any feedback from the worker. That's why I want the loading process to be tried a maximum of two more times if it fails. If the file still could not be loaded, I would like to return a default data set so that I can get a feedback in any case

e.g.

```
data = "not loaded";

return {id, data}
```

Here is my loading function. I've already read something about try and catch, but I still don't have the necessary understanding of connecting this in connection with a total of three loading attempts and implementing it in my function.

```
async LoadData(newImages){

   const ids = newImages.map(el => el.id);
   const loader = new THREE.ImageBitmapLoader();   //from three.js library
                
   const sharedImageDatas = await Promise.all(
   ids.map(async (id) => {      
                            
      const url = app_constants.SECOND_IMAGE_LIBRARY + id;          
      let image = await loader.loadAsync(url);
                
      let canvas = new OffscreenCanvas(image.width, image.height); 
      let context = canvas.getContext('2d'); 
      context.drawImage( image, 0, 0 );
                
      let imageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, image.width, image.height);
                        
      const data = new Uint8Array(new SharedArrayBuffer(imageData.data.length));
      data.set(imageData.data, 0);
 
      image = canvas = context = imageData = null;
            
      return {id, data}; 
      })
   );   
        
   return sharedImageDatas;         
}
```

Can anyone give me any recommendations on how to extend my function to suit what I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rewrote your function - add a check for 3 tries.

```js
async function LoadData(newImages, maxTries = 3) {
  const ids = newImages.map(el => el.id);
  const loader = new THREE.ImageBitmapLoader(); //from three.js library
  const sharedImageDatas = await Promise.all(ids.map(async (id) => {
    let tries = 0;
    while (tries < maxTries) {
      const url = app_constants.SECOND_IMAGE_LIBRARY + id;
      try {
        let image = await loader.loadAsync(url);
        let canvas = new OffscreenCanvas(image.width, image.height);
        let context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
        let imageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, image.width, image.height);
        const data = new Uint8Array(new SharedArrayBuffer(imageData.data.length));
        data.set(imageData.data, 0);
        image = canvas = context = imageData = null;
        return { id, data };
      } catch (error) {
        tries++;
      }
    }
    return { id, data: "not loaded" };
  }));
  return sharedImageDatas;
}
```

Comment: That's exactly right. That's exactly what I imagined, but I hadn't done anything with try/catch until jet. And learned something again, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example wrapper function that you should use for map callback.

```
async function withRetries(fn) {
  let count = 0;
  const defaultValue = {};

  while (count < 3) {
    try {
      const data = await fn();
      return data;
    } catch (error) {
      count++;
    }
  }

  return defaultValue;
}
```